# Code generation for "scheduler chain" in SQLDeveloper 3.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbms-scheduler

I use the visual editor to create schduler chains in sqldeveloper3.2. But faced with a problem - can not get the SQL code of the chain, namely the sequence of requests `create_chain`, `define_chain_step`, `define_chain_rule` (from `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package).

In addition a number of properties have created steps and rules can not be changed like a `program_name` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_Metadata can be used to pull the definitions.

When I last tried this in 10.2.0.4 it did not pull the scheduler rules -- I pulled them by just reading the relevant system tables using SQL.

```
select 'exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE('''||chain_name||''','''||condition||''','''||action||''','''||rule_name||''','''||comments||''');'
from user_scheduler_chain_rules
where chain_name = 'EXPORT';
```

I always found it more robust to completely drop and redefine a schedule rather than modify them in place. Some notes here: http://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/category/oracle/dbms_scheduler/

Comment: It seems I did not properly expressed. I need to generate the SQL code from the visual presentation schduler chain in SQLDeveloper. But thanks for the proposed method of building query.